# Floating window in android

Tags: android

i have seen in android 2.2 that on click of the contact a floating window appear with the mail message and call.Is this a widget or dialog in android or something implemented by activity.

Kindly help me to suggest any tutorial.

Regards

Deepak goel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A floating window in Android is, generally, a Dialog or Dialog sub-class.   You can also style a standard activity to look like a dialog using themes.  Please refer to the official android documentation here:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are talking about. If you are talking about [Alerts/Dialogs refer this link](http://huuah.com/dialog-boxes-in-android/) on how to do alert boxes (which is again kinda floating on top of the activity )